# Is it possible to create this mysql Function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm a newbie in mysql programming, and i would create a mysql function ***myFunction*** with a string parametre; this function query  ***myTable*** and return a string from the query-result like this example :

```
myTable
 ---------------
|id   |  value   |
 ---------------
| id1 |value1    |
| id2 |value2    |
| id3 |value3    |
| id4 |value4    |
 ---------------
```

Calling this function is like this

```
myFunction('value2#value1#value4')
```

and must return

```
'id2#id1#id4'
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure you'd need a function for that, but if you absolutely needed one, you'd probably need to look into PREPAREd statements, and the REPLACE & FIELD string functions. Or you might need to parse the parameter and look into CURSORs.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me,have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a demo of how you can do it, of course you can put all together but I find it cleaner to split the functions.

Check the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dda93/1)

**My table**

```
-- the table def
create table myTable (id char(3), value char(6));
insert into myTable values( 'id1', 'value1');
insert into myTable values( 'id2', 'value2');
insert into myTable values( 'id3', 'value3');
insert into myTable values( 'id4', 'value4');
```

**Get a specific id**

```
-- get Id by Value
CREATE function getIdByValue( theValue TEXT ) 
RETURNS TEXT READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE theId TEXT;
  DECLARE ok INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id FROM myTable where value = theValue;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ok = TRUE;

  SET theId = '';

  OPEN crs;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH crs INTO theId;
    IF ok THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE crs;
  RETURN theId;
END//
```

**MyFunction as you describe**

```
-- the myFunction, usage: myFunction('value2#value1#value4')
CREATE function myFunction( v TEXT )
RETURNS TEXT READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE theId TEXT;
  DECLARE theIds TEXT;
  DECLARE theValue TEXT;
  DECLARE vInstr INT;

  SET theId  = '';
  SET theIds = '';

  v_loop: LOOP

    SET vInstr = INSTR(v,'#');
    IF vInstr = 0 THEN
      SET theValue = v;
      SET theId = getIdByValue(theValue);
    ELSE
      SET theValue = SUBSTRING(v, 1, vInstr-1);
      SET v = SUBSTRING(v, vInstr+1);
      SET theId = concat( getIdByValue(theValue), '#');
    END IF;

    SET theIds = CONCAT(theIds, theId);

    IF vInstr = 0 THEN
      LEAVE v_loop;
    END IF;

  END LOOP; 

  RETURN theIds;
END//
```

**The call**

```
SELECT myFunction( 'value2' );
SELECT myFunction( 'value2#value4' );
SELECT myFunction( 'value2#value4#value1' );
SELECT myFunction( 'value2#value4#value1#value3' );
```

**The results**

```
id2
id2#id4
id2#id4#id1
id2#id4#id1#id3
```

Comment: Thank you all very much, that exactly what i want but, for the performance reasons what is the best ?

 Solution of @Uueerdo
 Or solution of MrSimpleMind

Thank you very much

Comment: The queries are totally different, you asked for a question. And the function will operate much faster then writing code that receives one id a time, as the function will do one db call (no overhead for network etc). But Uueerdo query is faster as it does all in one query. BUT remember that your question is about sending a string with # as separator. And to get a result in same order only the function will achieve that. Uueerdos does not guarantee any order.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like,

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction (param1) RETURNS datatype
[NOT] DETERMINISTIC 
statements
```

check this link for more information
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you couldn't just run this kind of query?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY FIELD(`value`, 'value2', 'value1', 'value4'))
FROM myTable
WHERE `value` IN ('value2','value1','value4')
;
```

Edited: Added `value` as first argument to FIELD() function to make it return the ids in the proper order.

Comment: Remember just that the order will not be guaranteed, this will not return id2,id1,id4. But maybe he can live with that...

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, It wouldn't have the way I originally wrote it, but with the edit I just made it should.